# Is it possible to get email over JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, email

It would be cool if I could retrieve gmail or some other mail service via JSON.  Is there any JSON enabled service that allows this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends if the mail service in question provides an API.

- Yahoo: http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/
- Gmail: http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/faq.html
- Aol: http://dev.aol.com/api/openmail

Otherwise you'd have to develop your own application which would consume the data from the mail service and publish it as JSON

Answer (score 0):

Not designed for personal email, but this service delivers email as JSON: http://postmarkapp.com/inbound

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, [mailinatorpro.com](https://www.mailinatorpro.com/) offers this service. I haven't tested it, so I cannot give you my opinion on it.

From 20$ a month, you can have access to the JSON API

Answer (score 0):

This can parse all incoming mail on your own server (Postfix for example) to JSON: https://github.com/Newsman/MailToJson

I guess the code can be changed to fetch from Gmail via pop3 and parse it as JSON.